openxlsx formula is not translating correctly
I want to implement the following formula using openxlsx: =IF(COUNTIF(E3:G3,"none")=3,"N/A",AVERAGE(IF(ISNUMBER(--E3:G3),--E3:G3,""))) to each row
This formula works perfectly in excel given the dataframe, however when I use openxlsx, it gives me the following:
=IF(COUNTIF(E3:G3, "none") = 3, "N/A", AVERAGE(IF(ISNUMBER(--@E3:G3), --@E3:G3, "")))
and doesn't give me the correct answer, how do I fix this and get rid of the @ symbol.
library(openxlsx)

# Create a new workbook and add a worksheet
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet1")

# Example data: write some sample data to columns E, F, and G starting from row 1
example_data <- data.frame(
  E = c(1, NA, 3, "none", 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), 
  F = c(11, 12, "none", 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20),
  G = c(21, 22, 23, 24, "none", 26, 27, 28, 29, 30)
)
writeData(wb, "Sheet1", example_data, startCol = 5, startRow = 1)

# Determine the number of rows in your data
num_rows <- nrow(example_data)

# Function to create the formula with conditions
create_custom_formula <- function(row) {
  sprintf(
    "=IF(COUNTIF(E%d:G%d, \"*none*\") = 3, \"N/A\", AVERAGE(IF(ISNUMBER(--E%d:G%d), --E%d:G%d, \"\")))",
    row, row, row, row, row, row
  )
}

# Apply the function to each row and write the formulas to column H
lapply(1:num_rows, function(row) {
  writeFormula(wb, "Sheet1", x = create_custom_formula(row + 1), startCol = 8, startRow = row + 1)
})

# Set the column width for better visibility
setColWidths(wb, "Sheet1", cols = 8, widths = 15)

# Set the header for the new column (H1) to "Average"
writeData(wb, "Sheet1", "Average", startCol = 8, startRow = 1)

# Save the workbook
saveWorkbook(wb, "example_with_custom_averages.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)


Your formula is an array formula --E3:G3 creates an array. In modern Excel this is hidden, no curly brackets around the formula. In openxlsx you should be able to use the array argument. Below an answer using openxlsx2, here you can hide the array formula with the cm argument.
library(openxlsx2)

# separate numbers and strings in mixed data frame
options("openxlsx2.string_nums" = TRUE)

# -- data
example_data <- data.frame(
  E = c(1, NA, 3, "none", 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), 
  F = c(11, 12, "none", 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20),
  G = c(21, 22, 23, 24, "none", 26, 27, 28, 29, 30)
)

# --custom function
create_custom_formula <- function(row) {
  sprintf(
    "=IF(COUNTIF(E%d:G%d, \"none\") = 3, \"N/A\", AVERAGE(IF(ISNUMBER(--E%d:G%d), --E%d:G%d, \"\")))",
    row, row, row, row, row, row
  )
}

num_rows <- seq_len(nrow(example_data)) + 1

# -- create workbook with data
wb <- wb_workbook()$
  add_worksheet()$
  add_data(
    dims = wb_dims(x = example_data, from_col = 5),
    x = example_data, na.strings = NULL
  )$
  add_formula(
    x = create_custom_formula(num_rows), 
    dims = wb_dims(x = example_data, from_col = 8, from_row = 2),
    array = TRUE
  )

if (interactive()) wb$open()


